# cannot take data from DB and use it in VUE script

Tags: json, laravel, vue-component

I try to take data from DB and use it in VUE script, but in console I see message

```
GET http://lara7.test/api/furnitura 401 (Unauthorized)
```

In Chrome devtools Network tab I see response

**furnitura**

```
{"message":"Unauthenticated."}
```

Here is my code

**routes\api.php**

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group( function () {
  Route::resource('furnitura', 'API\FurnituraController');
});
```

**App\Http\Controllers\API\BaseController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

abstract class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function sendResponse($result, $message)
    {
      $response = [
            'success' => true,
            'data'    => $result,
            'message' => $message,
        ];

        return response()->json($response, 200);
    }

    public function sendError($error, $errorMessages = [], $code = 404)
    {
      $response = [
            'success' => false,
            'message' => $error,
        ];

        if(!empty($errorMessages)){
            $response['data'] = $errorMessages;
        }

        return response()->json($response, $code);
    }
}
```

**App\Http\Controllers\API\FurnituraController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

class FurnituraController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $furnitura = Furnitura::all();

        return $this->sendResponse($furnitura->toArray(), 'Furnitura retrieved successfully.');
    }
}
```

**resources\js\app.js**

```
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
...
...
mounted() {
    console.log("Vue ROOT instance mounted");
    axios.get('/api/furnitura').then(response => this.furnitura = response.data);
    console.log(this.furnitura);
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, you do not pass the auth: API middleware. You are getting 401 from middleware.

- maybe you use token for user validation or API user validation that token is missing

Comment: Where this token can be found? I don't have user management yet on this project. Users table is empty. I have User model in my project, but it is just created by default when install Laravel.

Comment: So I didn't create myself anything about tokens and user validation.

Comment: so remove the middleware('auth:api')-> from your route or just write 
Route::resource('furnitura', 'API\FurnituraController');

Comment: can you make my answer write for pressing vote? It makes me inspired. thanks